# How do I merge the headers from one csv file with another csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv, merge

What I'm trying to ask is, how would I use the headers from one csv as the headers for another csv file? It would kind of be like a merge, except the first csv file is JUST headers, and the second csv file has JUST data

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this will work

```
dn <- read.csv("d-names.txt")
dd <- read.csv("d-data.txt",header=FALSE)

names(dd)<-names(dn)
```

Just assign the names from one data.frame to the other. Just make sure the files have exactly the same number of columns.